# Undescriptive capacitor and inductor values in audio-amp datasheet

Tags: capacitor, audio, inductor

I was learning about audio amplifiers and came across the STA516B IC. To my surprise, the example circuits feature some values for capacitors and inductors which seem a bit high for me. So I wanted to ask if I was missing something or if these components are somehow special and are really meant to have such high values. Thank you for your answers[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plWMh.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> To my surprise, the example circuits feature some values for
>   capacitors and inductors which seem a bit high for me. So I wanted to
>   ask if I was missing something or if these components are somehow
>   special and are really meant to have such high values.

Almost certainly the character "\$\mu\$" is failing to be displayed on the PDF document that you used. Try digging a bit deeper on the ST website to see if there are any other references that do use the \$\mu\$ character.

For instance here's a schematic that does show the rogue character: -

[image]

Taken from ST's page [here](https://www.st.com/en/audio-ics/sta508.html).

Comment: Omega has fallen out too. Someone at ST should have his/her computer's Windows OS updated and language packs and fonts installed.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll dig deeper myself next time :)